# Extract Lines between two tags

Tags: powershell

I have following sample data from text file

```
l1
l2
Start :
a1
a2
a3
-}
l3
l4
l5
Start :
a4
a5
a6
-}
```

I want to extract lines between two tages "Start : " and -}

I tried to extract details with regexp but output was coming in one line. I want output with newline

Pl help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select between multiple lines in power shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53393884/how-to-select-between-multiple-lines-in-power-shell)

Comment: See also purpose: [`#15136` Add -From and -To parameters to Select-String](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15136)

Answer (score 1):

This will get the raw content of the text file (meaning it will pull in the carriage returns and new lines).  Then with that data it performs a regular expression to extract the data that you want between the "Start :" and the "-}" pulling all the matches.  Then it just outputs the value for each match found.  If you want to store that in a variable you would do that in the last foreach loop.

```
$file = Get-Content -path "C:\text.txt" -Raw
$wantedData = ($file | select-string '(?<=Start\s:\n)[\w\s]*(?=-})' -allMatches | 
    foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {$_.Value})
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best approach but this will work as long as it is always in that format:

```
$i = "l1 l2 Start : a1 a2 a3 -} l3 l4 l5 Start : a4 a5 a6 -}"
$i = $i.split(':').split('-}')

foreach ($line in $i) {
   if ($line -notlike "*start*" ){ $line.trim() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will there always be 3 values between start and -} ?

If so, then:

```
$Content = Get-Content -path C:\Text.txt
$content | Select-String -Pattern "Start :" -Context 0,3 | foreach {$_.Context.DisplayPostContext}
```