# How to select between multiple lines in power shell?

Tags: powershell

I am using Get-Content (gc) here. I need to delete a set of lines defined by the start and end marker. But for some reasons, the command that I use does not work. Do you know what I am missing here?

**Command that I have tried:**

```
powershell -Command ((gc test.txt) -replace '"/\#start.*\#end/gms"','')
```

**test.txt:**

```
line1
line2
#start
line3
line4
#end
line5
```

**Expected output:**

```
line1
line2
line5
```

Comment: Sooo, then why the batch-file tag?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem, your regex is wrong. PowerShell does not use PCRE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-Content` reads the file into an Array of strings. Use `Get-Content -Raw` to read it as one string.

```
powershell -Command ((Get-Content -Path test.txt -Raw) -replace '(?smi)#start(.*)#end\r?\n','')
```

Comment: Does that code actually work for you? That regex looks flawed for .net

Comment: @Matt Updated the regex as well. It should work now.

Comment: You are missing the new line after `#end`. Add a `\r?\n`

Comment: Added it. Thanks @Matt

Answer (score 2):

As answered by @TobyU, using the `-Raw` will easily resolve the issue but there is a downside to this quick solution:

PowerShell is extremely good in streaming objects, that's why `Get-Content` supplies a stream of lines in the first place. If you use the `-Raw` and/or brackets, you choke the output pipeline. This is not a big issue for a small list but could cause performance issues and/or memory issues when the list gets larger.

In respect of the PowerShell streaming pipeline you might consider to resolve it like this:

```
$On = $True; Get-Content -Path test.txt | Where {If ($_ -eq '#start') {$On = $False} ElseIf ($_ -eq '#end') {$On = $True} Else {$On}}
```

In this command, `Where` filters the `#Start` and `#End` as it has in both cases no output at all and passes the rest of the lines when `$on` is `$True`.