# Extract specific text and extract

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a PowerShell to read a SQL Dump text file and read this file from a specific search point '`CREATE TABLE fks_common.bo_bdsvragen`' until the first place that I find '`;)`'. The lines between I want to extract and write to a new file. I am just starting to learn PowerShell and definite need some help. Also it would be nice that the solution perform since the search dump file is very big (40Gb).

```
$Zoektext = '*CREATE TABLE fks_common.bo_bdsvragen*'

$FILE = Get-Content "c:\scripts\dump.sql" | Where-object {$_ -like $Zoektext}

foreach ($LINE in $FILE)
{
    $Tekst = 'Op regel ' + $Line.ReadCount + ' staat ' + $LINE 
    Write-Output $Tekst
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select between multiple lines in power shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53394705/1701026)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have swapped the characters for the end of the table declaration `;)` should be `);`

With a large file like this, it would be fastest to use `switch`.

Suppose your `dump.sql` file looks like this:

```
blah
blahblahblah
blahblahblahblah
CREATE TABLE fks_common.bo_bdsvragen (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
more blah
and a lot more blahblah
```

Then you can do this to exctract the text you're interested in like below:

```
# create two regex escaped strings for the beginning and end of the table declaration
$tableBegin = [regex]::Escape('CREATE TABLE fks_common.bo_bdsvragen')
$tableEnd   = [regex]::Escape(');')
# set a boolean flag to $false
$foundBegin = $false

# loop through the text line-by-line and capture only what you seek
$result = switch -Regex -File 'c:\scripts\dump.sql' {
    $tableBegin { $foundBegin = $true; $_ }  # set the flag and output this line
    $tableEnd   { if ($foundBegin) { $_ ; break }  }         # we've reached the end of the CREATE_TABLE declaration
    default     { if ($foundBegin) {$_ } }   # only output this line if $foundBegin is $true
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to new file
$result | Set-Content -Path 'c:\scripts\table.sql'
```

Output:

```
CREATE TABLE fks_common.bo_bdsvragen (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: Hi Theo, Thanks for this sample and what a powerfull utility is switch.  It almost do the trick. The problem is that when it will find  the signs ); first it does not work and stop and shows ); als result. This would be the case when you are looking for the 2e of 3e... create table in the file. It this could be resolved then you make my day.

Comment: @Ron Ah, yes. It's fixed now.