# PowerShell: Need to get values between two lines/rows

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a `.txt` file that has a structure like this.

```
Configure text Example
Configure text Example
Configure text Example
---Start of Data---
Data I want to grab
Data I want to grab
Data I want to grab
Data I want to grab
---End of Data---
```

What would be the best way for me to grab the data between the two rows (Start of Data & End of Data)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract Lines between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001716/extract-lines-between-two-tags)

Comment: See also propose: [`#15136` Add -From and -To parameters to Select-String](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15136)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select between multiple lines in power shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53393884/how-to-select-between-multiple-lines-in-power-shell)

Answer (score 2):

Regex would be your best bet here, it seems.

```
$file = "data.txt"
$pattern = "---Start of Data---([\s\S]*?)---End of Data---"

$string = Get-Content $file -Raw
$result = [regex]::match($string, $pattern).Groups[1].Value
```

`$result` will contain the output that you want.

Comment: That won't work, you will need to use the [`-Raw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content#example-6--get-raw-content) parameter to `Get-Content` as a  single string.

Comment: Agreed. The OP can use `-Raw` if he requires so. But the above answer will solve the problem which he has asked in the question.

Comment: The [Regex.Match Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match)  doesn't have an overload for a string *array* (`String[]`) therefore PowerShell "conveniently" converts it to a single string (`"$String"`) where all newlines are changed to spaces (including the `$result`).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @iRon - I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: You also need to change your `$pattern` to something like `"---Start of Data---([\s\S]*?)---End of Data---"` as dot (`.`) doesn't match newlines.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Yash's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68901759/11954025), here is some fun stuff you can do with `switch` if you want to catch different parts or sections that are identifiable by some start and end line

```
$text = @'
Configure text Example
Configure text Example
Configure text Example
---Start Part A---
Data I want to grab
Data I want to grab
Data I want to grab
Data I want to grab
---End A---
Some other text that isn't needed
Some other text that isn't needed
---Start Section B---
Data I want to grab in B
Data I want to grab in B
Data I want to grab in B
Data I want to grab in B
Data I want to grab in B
---End B---
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$inside = $false
$pattern = '---(?:Start|End) ?(\D+?)---'

switch -Regex ($text) {
    $pattern {
        $inside = !$inside
        $section = $Matches[1]
    }
    default {
        if ($inside) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Section = $section
                Line = $_
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Section   Line
-------   ----
Part A    Data I want to grab
Part A    Data I want to grab
Part A    Data I want to grab
Part A    Data I want to grab
Section B Data I want to grab in B
Section B Data I want to grab in B
Section B Data I want to grab in B
Section B Data I want to grab in B
Section B Data I want to grab in B
```